# How do we compute this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, logarithms

Given:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
How do we show that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)4^n} = ln3$$

Hints given are that

$$f(1/2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)4^n}$$

and $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

From what I understand, there isn't a series definition of logarithms is there?

Answer (score 1):

From $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$

you get
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2x^{2n}}
= \frac 2{1 - x^2} = \frac 1{1-x} + \frac 1{1+x}
$$
So as $f(0) = 0$:
$$
f(x) = \log (1+x) - \log(1-x) = \log\frac{1+x}{1-x}
$$

From this, just evaluate $f(1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By integrating $\frac{1}{1 + x}$, $\frac{1}{1 - x}$ together with their respective geometric series, show that $f(x)$ is exactly the taylor expansion of $$\ln\left(\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}\right)$$

and then compute the required series using the fact that it is equal to $f(x)$ at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$ \frac{1}{4^n (2n+1)} = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{2n}\,dx $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n(2n+1)} = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\left.\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right|_{0}^{1/2}=\color{red}{\log 3}. $$